# Send listing user a message undefined local variable or method `user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently trying to develop the following functionality:
Users can list listings. Others can click on these listings, click apply, fill out a form and click on submit. This form should of course be send to the listing user. I am stuck on getting this last part right. I'm working with ActionMailer and this is what I got:

listing_controller.rb

```
def send_mail
    @user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
    name = params[:name]
    email = params[:email]
    body = params[:comments]
    UserMailer.contact_email(name, email, body).deliver
    redirect_to contact_path, notice: 'Message sent'
end
```

apply.html.erb

```
<div class="top">
<div class="container-content">
    <div class="container">
        <%= form_tag(send_mail_path) do %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= label_tag 'name', 'Name' %>
                <%= text_field_tag 'name', nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Your Name' %>
            </div>
           <div class="form-group">
               <%= label_tag 'email', 'Email' %>
               <%= email_field_tag 'email', nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Your Email Address' %>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
               <%= label_tag 'comments', 'Comments' %>
               <%= text_area_tag 'comments', nil, class: 'form-control', rows: 4, placeholder: 'Comments...' %>
           </div>
           <%= submit_tag nil, class: 'btn btn-default btn-about pull-right' %>
       <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(to: user.email, subject: "Welcome to My Awesome Site")
  end



def contact_email(name, email, body)
    @user = user
    @name = name
    @email = email
    @body = body
    mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Contact Request')
end
```

end

routes

```
match '/send_mail', to: 'listings#send_mail', via: 'post'
```

I got it to work that when a user signs up he is getting an email. But I cannot seem to get it to work that users can contact the listing user. Right now I am getting the following error undefined local variable or method `user' but I am not sure if the setup is completely right.

Please let me know if you need more information.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second line of the contact_email method references the variable 'user' which you have not set anywhere (as the error says). But you don't seem to need it anyway. Try changing:

```
mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Contact Request')
```

to

```
mail(to: email, subject: 'Contact Request')
```

and getting rid of the line:

```
@user = user
```

but also think about what you're doing in the mailer code. Why are you setting the instance (@) variables if you're not using them?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would like to send an email to the user who posted the listing. Would (to: email) understand who listed the item?

Comment: Okay so I switched the code and it works! That's great, but how does the application understand that (to: email) belongs to the listing email?

Comment: Sorry, I did not read closely enough. from what I can see, your apply form does not have any data that would identify the listing that the user is applying for. So you might want to load the listing.id as a hidden element in the apply form. Then your controller can load the listing and find the listing user.

Comment: Okay I will try do that. But it is working already. Do you know why?

Comment: The mail should be getting sent to the email address on the form. If that field is being populated form the listing, rather than being data entered by the user, then you may be all set.

Comment: It does not look like the mail contains any reference to the actual listing, though. So this could be confusing if a user has multiple listings up. If they get a mail, how will they know which listing the mail applies to?